# Setting up an IBL2403 motor driver

Tags: motor, driver, software

I received an shiny new [IBL2403](http://www.technosoftmotion.com/en/intelligent-drives-and-motors/other-drives/closed-frame/ibl2403) the other day:

[IBL2403 http://www.realmotiontech.com/Images1/IBL2403.jpg](http://www.realmotiontech.com/Images1/IBL2403.jpg)

However, I've been having difficultly using the [EasyMotion Studio](http://www.technosoftmotion.com/ESM-um-html/) software that comes with it.

---

When I try and set up the driver for the first time, the wizard tries to deploy some test code (i.e. to send back the terminal voltage) on the driver. However, this results in the error message:

[image: This setup is incompatible with your drive/motor]

Asking for details on test failure gives:

> An internal error has occurred in the application. Possible causes:
>
> - The board is not responding;
> - Your board codification does not match with the selected amplifier codification;
> - Some of the configuration files are not related with the version of program;
> - You might be down with the system resources.

WRT to the first bullet, the driver is known to be responding, as I can successfully send it serial commands. I'm at a total loss to the meaning of the other three error messages.

How can I set up this driver, when the reason for setup failing is that the driver is not set up?

Comment: Not sure if this belongs here, but it's loosely related, and at least now someone can hopefully google those nonsensical error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EasyMotion studio software does not work properly with a brand new driver. Instead, you have to put an incomplete setup file on with an external tool.

Within EasyMotion studio, select *Application→Create EEPROM Programmer File→Setup only...*, and create a `.sw` file.

Now open the "EEPROM Programmer" software that comes with the install of EasyMotion, and write the file to the driver. For me, this succeeded without errors.

---

Now that there's some initial setup on the driver, the rest of the configuration should work from EasyMotion studio.